# Create SharePoint variation labels using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

Can anyone tell me how to create SharePoint 2013 variation labels using client-side object model (CSOM). I know it is possible using SSOM and Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

### How to create Variation Labels in SharePoint 2013/Online via CSOM

[VariationsClient class](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/6757a1dab43eb320aa6c) is intended for managing Variation Labels in SharePoint 2013.

The following operations are currently supported:

- `VariationsClient.CreateLabel` method is used for create Variation Label
- `VariationsClient.GetLabelsList` method gets Variation Labels on site

### Usage

```
var variationsClient = new VariationsClient(ctx);
var siteLanguages = new[] {"en-US","ru-RU","fi-FI","nl-NL"};
foreach (var language in siteLanguages)
{
   var isSource = (language == "en-US");
   variationsClient.CreateLabel(new CultureInfo(language), isSource);    
}
```

### Result

[image]